# Permanently adding an item to an existing alertdialog?

Tags: android, xml, addition, android-alertdialog

My goal is to permanently add an item to an existing AlertDialog.

The XML array for the AlertDialog is:

```
<array name="serverchoice">
    <item>@string/chicago_server</item>
    <item>@string/london_server</item>
    <item>@string/sanjose_server</item>
    <item>@string/washington_server</item>
    <item>@string/chicagoq_server</item>
    <item>@string/londonq_server</item>
    <item>@string/sanjoseq_server</item>
    <item>@string/washingtonq_server</item>
</array>
```

As you can see it's a list of servers, I'd like a user to be able to add their own server rather than having to use the preset servers.

I have created a page with a text box and a button so a user can enter a server. When the user clicks the Add Server button I'd like the entry to be added to the list.

Currently, when the user chooses a menu item from the AlertDialog it gets processed like this:

```
    // Choose Server method

    private void openServerDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)     
        .setTitle(R.string.server_title)  
        .setItems(R.array.serverchoice,   
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
                    int i) {
                setServer(i);   
            }
        })
        .show();
    }

private void setServer(int i) {   


        if (String.valueOf(i).equals("0")){
            CustomServer.setText("mcsord.visualware.com");
        }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("1")){
            CustomServer.setText("mcslhr.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("2")){
            CustomServer.setText("mcssjc.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("3")){
            CustomServer.setText("mcsiad.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("4")){
            CustomServer.setText("qualitytestord.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("5")){
            CustomServer.setText("qualitytestlhr.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("6")){
            CustomServer.setText("qualitytestsjc.visualware.com");
            }
        else if (String.valueOf(i).equals("7")){
            CustomServer.setText("qualitytestiad.visualware.com");
            }

}
```

All I want to do right now is get another permanent item when the user chooses to add one. My last question regarding this wasn't clear enough. I don't want an options menu or context menu.

Thanks

EDIT:

Having looked around even more I can see people are saying it's not possible to dynamically add to an array list.

Currently I have an optionsmenu that presents itself when the menu button is pressed on the android phone itself. The code I use for that is:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_server:
                    addNewServer();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to create ANOTHER options menu and use that instead of the AlertDialog shown above? Or will I run into the same issue that a list item can't be added dynamically.

I DO HAVE the ability for a user to enter their own URL but it doesn't save it, they'd have to keep typing it in each time.

Thanks

Comment: as far as i know you cannot edit those xml files at run time.  you will need to use some other persistence store service (sqlite or a webservice) to save the added entries to.  then when it comes time to show them you need to check the alternative location and add those to the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nor sure if I understood your question... but I'll try to answer.
First, you can add dinamically new options to the alertDialog after you inflate them. What you can't do is add new lines to the xml from where you inflate them.

Having said that, you need to store the new servers somewhere when the activity finish, so you can recover them later. For this you have several options, and I'll start with the one I believe is the simplest:

Store the servers in a shared preferences file:

Saving example

```
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putString("server1", "serverName1");
    editor.putString("server2", "serverName2");
    editor.commit();
```

Reading example:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.getString("server1", "defaultValue");
    preferences.getString("server2", "defaultValue");
```

You can also use a database to store the values. This would be better if you expect to have a list with hundreds of servers, as the performance of previous solution would be pour in this case.

Finally, you could store the information in a file, but that would require more code and I don't see any true benefit of it.

If I didn't answer you question, just let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Luis, I think this is the kind of thing I'm after. I would only expect a couple of servers to be added to the list. We are including the app as an example of what can be done using our API, so it doesn't have to be extensive.

Comment: So to start with the preferences file would contain the pre set servers as listed in my initial question?

Can I then add to the shared preferences file so next time it's called it includes the recently added entry?

Comment: Yes. You should on first application run (or just test is no server is yet defined in the shared preferences) add your default list of servers. Later you can add to the list any other server that the user type in, just using the same code above. Just have in mind that you may need to remove the line of code "editor.clear()", if you are not rewrinting all the servers, but only adding a new one, as this line remove all the information in the shared preferences file before append the new values. regards

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the defaults in the xml file but you'll need to store the custom servers in a database.  Then you can pull from both sources into a single array and put that in the dialog.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: I believe CaseyB is suggesting that the example of "items" would reside in a database somewhere and so you'd probably need to concatenate the default (in your xml) with the database elements and then you can add them to the list at that point. Is this a correct assumption CaseyB?