# Android:onSaveInstanceState. How do you save entries into EditVew?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save user entries into a form, but for some reason I can not get it to work. When I kill the application and restart the data does not appear.

My aim is that if a user is halfway through completing the form and the application is killed, that when the application relaunches the entries will still remain. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public final static String EXTRA_FROM = "com.example.assignment1.FROM";
     public final static String EXTRA_TO = "com.example.assignment1.TO";
     public final static String EXTRA_CC = "com.example.assignment1.CC";
     public final static String EXTRA_BCC = "com.example.assignment1.BCC";
     public final static String EXTRA_SUBJECT = "com.example.assignment1.SUBJECT";
     public final static String EXTRA_COMPOSE = "com.example.assignment1.COMPOSE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        EditText emailTo =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
        EditText emailCc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCc);
        EditText emailBcc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailBcc);
        EditText emailSubject =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailSubject);
        EditText emailCompose =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCompose);

        String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
        String to = emailTo.getText().toString();
        String cc = emailCc.getText().toString();
        String bcc = emailBcc.getText().toString();
        String subject = emailSubject.getText().toString();
        String compose = emailCompose.getText().toString();

        outState.putString(EXTRA_FROM, from);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_TO, to);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_CC, cc);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_COMPOSE, compose);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)
    {

        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        EditText emailTo =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
        EditText emailCc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCc);
        EditText emailBcc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailBcc);
        EditText emailSubject =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailSubject);
        EditText emailCompose =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCompose);

        String from = savedState.getString(EXTRA_FROM);
        String to = savedState.getString(EXTRA_TO);
        String cc = savedState.getString(EXTRA_CC);
        String bcc = savedState.getString(EXTRA_BCC);
        String subject = savedState.getString(EXTRA_SUBJECT);
        String compose = savedState.getString(EXTRA_COMPOSE);

        emailFrom.setText(from);
        emailTo.setText(to);
        emailCc.setText(cc);
        emailBcc.setText(bcc);
        emailSubject.setText(subject);
        emailCompose.setText(compose);
    }

    public void emailSend (View sendButton) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayEmailActivity.class);
        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        EditText emailTo =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
        EditText emailCc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCc);
        EditText emailBcc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailBcc);
        EditText emailSubject =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailSubject);
        EditText emailCompose =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCompose);

        String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
        String to = emailTo.getText().toString();
        String cc = emailCc.getText().toString();
        String bcc = emailBcc.getText().toString();
        String subject = emailSubject.getText().toString();
        String compose = emailCompose.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM,from);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TO,to);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CC,cc);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BCC,bcc);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPOSE,compose);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Recover the entries from an application restart due to orientation change, or from an application that was quited by user?

Comment: Recover the entries from the application that was quitted by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save a few items your best shot is to use SharedPreferences.

I've put an example some time ago on this post: [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532476/permanently-adding-an-item-to-an-existing-alertdialog/12533138#12533138).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> When I kill the application and restart the data does not appear.

Of course. If you kill the application (e.g., task killer), your saved instance state goes away. To handle this scenario, you need to persist your data to a file, database, etc.

To test whether or not `onSaveInstanceState()` works, rotate the screen or do some other type of configuration change.