# Android: SharedPreferences. How to implement them properly

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store a user entry into an EditText field however when I exit the application it does not appear.

So for example a user types in his/her name and then exits the application. When the user returns and launches the Application the users name appears in the EditText field. However I can't get this to work. I believe its to do with sharedPreferences but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm quite new to android and java so finding this quite difficult. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public final static String EXTRA_FROM = "com.example.assignment1.FROM";


     @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
            String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
            outState.putString(EXTRA_FROM, from);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)
        {

            EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
            String from = savedState.getString(EXTRA_FROM);
            emailFrom.setText(from);

        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void emailSend (View sendButton) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayEmailActivity.class);

        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM,from);

        SharedPreferences saveFrom = getSharedPreferences(EXTRA_FROM, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = saveFrom.edit();
        editor.putString(EXTRA_FROM, from);
        editor.commit();

        String storedfrom = saveFrom.getString(EXTRA_FROM, from);
        emailFrom.setText(storedfrom);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Second Activity

```
 public class DisplayEmailActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_email);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            String from = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_FROM);
            TextView textFrom =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailFrom);
            textFrom.setText(from);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_email, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? SharedPreferences is used to store some data so that for example you have access next time you launch application.

Comment: Google search it... you're better off finding some sample code online than asking an incredibly general question about it here.

Comment: I was aiming for that when the user exits the application, the entry made into the form would still be visible in the EditText field. So for example in the form "FROM" the user name "TOM" would be stored in the EditText field when the user launches the application again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after you store value in your `EditText emailFrom`, you have to save it in SharedPreferences like this:

```
String from = emailFrom.getText().toString(); // Getting String value from EditText and storing it in "from" String
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesFile", 0); // Opening SharedPreferences 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); // Opening editor for SharedPreferences
editor.putString("exampleName", from); // You are putting here a String "from" and give it a "exampleName" name. Later you will use this name to restore data.
```

And then when you launch your application, you need to load data from SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesFile", 0); // Again opening SharedPreferences
String from = settings.getString("exampleName", ""); // The second argument is the default value. The default value will be set if there wasn't saved any data with "exampleName" name
if(from != "") // If "from" is not empty, it means that the data was stored in SharedPreferences
   emailFrom.setText(from); // Setting text in your EditText
```

Comment: You forgot [`editor.commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) : *"Note that you must call commit() to have any changes you perform in the Editor actually show up in the SharedPreferences."*

Comment: I've tried implmenting the code above but to no avail(with editor.commit()). When you say you need to load data from SharedPreferences do you mean that it should be stored in the OnCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to save and restore the content of the EditText. However, this methods are called only when the application is being terminated by the OS to be immediatlly recreated (i.e. device rotation).

If you want to preserve values when the application is terminated by the user, you need to store it somewhere, a file, a database or in your case I would suggest SharedPreferences.

I've posted an answer to a similar question in: [SharePreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532476/permanently-adding-an-item-to-an-existing-alertdialog/12533138#12533138)

Good luck.